# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test error in SAKAI

Tags: java, maven, sakai

When i tried to build SAKAI with maven i encounter the following error. Is there anyone faced with the same problem? Also firstly i build master folder in sakai source folder (sakai-src) normally there should be a folder named repository inside .m2 folder (`c:/user/pc-user/.m2`) but don't exist.

- Sakai 10.7
- Maven 3.3.1
- Tomcat 7.0.72

---

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project external-calendaring-service-impl: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\apache\sakai-src\external-calendaring-service\impl\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :external-calendaring-service-impl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are certain times when some tests are causing the build to fail.
> Excluding them is one of the best workarounds to continue the build.
> Exclusions can be done by configuring the excludes property of the
> plugin.
>
> [Maven Surefire Plugin  / Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

My solution would be to check in C:\apache\sakai-src\external-calendaring-service\impl\target\surefire-reports for the failed tests and exclude them in your pom.xml.

```
  <project>
      [...]
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>
```

Another solution might be to run the following Maven command:

```
mvn clean install -X -e -DskipTests
```

Comment: Firstly thanks very much, second solution which you suggested resolved my problem but why couldn't create repository folder in .m2 folder?

Comment: If you provide me with full log, I could make a guess. For starters you could check your log for [INSTALL] tags. This shows you the path where the jars are about to be saved. If you can't find any lines with [INSTALL] than Maven might be cancelled the download of the dependencies base on the failed tests. Also the folder could be hidden, maybe.